# Importing between nested packages in Python 3

Tags: python, package, python-import

Running Python 3.6.1, and I'm trying to get a file (`world.py`) to import from another package in my project.

My directory structure:

```
+-- test_project
|   +-- sub_project1
|   |   +-- __init__.py
|   |   +-- hello.py
|   +-- sub_project2
|   |   +-- __init__.py
|   |   +-- world.py
```

`hello.py`:

```
def say_hello():
    return("Hello ")
```

`world.py`:

```
from test_project.sub_project1.hello import say_hello

print(say_hello() + "world!")
```

When I go into the `sub_project2` directory and run `world.py`, I keep getting this:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test_project'
```

I've tried rewriting the import statement to `from sub_project1.hello import say_hello`. I've also tried having the `test_project` directory in my PATH environment variable. I've tried having the `test_project`'s *parent* directory in my PATH. I've tried having the `sub_project2`'s directory in my PATH. I've searched for answers online and can't work out what I'm missing.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the path of "hello.py" to `sys.path`

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../sub_project1')

from hello import say_hello

print(say_hello() + "world!")
```

Output:

```
Hello world!
```

Source is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11158224/6900838). This discussion is really helpful.

**EDIT:** Because "sub_project1" has `__init__.py`, you can use:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..') #Adds upper directory sys.path

from sub_project1.hello import say_hello

print(say_hello() + "world!")
```

Comment: Thanks for that, this seems like the simplest solution. I love Python, but packages and importing can be an absolute pain sometimes...

Comment: You're welcome. I agree, and I love Python too. There's no rose without a thorn. Every language has tough sides. Also, don't forget to read the link I gave above, it's really helpful about importing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have to add your project to python path. The reason is that python first search in these locations:

1. the directory containing the input script (or the current directory).
2. PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
3. the installation-dependent default.

So, you have to add to `PYTHONPATH` environment variable the directory `C:\Users\your_user\dir_before_test_project\`